# Are ThomasNet.com's terms and conditions contradictory?

Tags: terms-of-service

ThomasNet.com is a directory for businesses to advertise themselves.
It requires that business owners themselves " agree that you will not use this website or our services or applications for ... commercial solicitations ."

This is contradictory. Is this even legally enforceable?

Source:https://www.thomasnet.com/terms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no contradiction. It says that

> you agree that you will not use this website or our services or
> applications for chain letters, junk mail, "spamming" or commercial
> solicitations or to send any message or Content that

[is clearly bad, as extensively described]

As a customer I can use the site to search for suppliers of bolts and request a quote, and as a bolt-supplier I can make my catalog of bolts available and can respond to requests for quotes. Nobody gets to use the website as a platform for launching commercial solicitations – spam, in one view of what span is. It's a business decision regarding how they will allow their platform to be used, and it is enforceable.

Comment: +1. Part of OP's confusion may be their misunderstanding of "commercial solicitations", which a quick google defined as "seeking the business of potential customers. The term usually refers to directly asking potential customers to purchase goods or services, rather than using advertisements."